# Is there a way to generate a customized CMakeLists.txt from VSCode's CMake-tools "Cmake: quick start"?

Tags: c++, cmake

When starting a new C++ project on VSCode with CMake Tools extension, we can run the "Cmake: quick start" command to generate a basic CMakeLists.txt file with basic project configuration. I would like to know if i can customize this generation so it includes some additional configuration on every new project. I like to use address sanitizer on even simple programs i create so i want to have it setup automatically.

Standard config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(filas VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(filas main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

include(CPack)
```

The additional config i want:

```
if(CMAKE_DEFAULT_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Debug")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address")
  target_link_options(filas
    BEFORE PUBLIC -fsanitize=undefined PUBLIC -fsanitize=address
  )
endif()
```

I'm a beginner at C++ and CMake and couldn't find this specific info so far.

Comment: I believe there is documentation for the cmake extension online. Did you try looking that up?

Comment: If you don't find what you're looking for, you can consider extracting those common things into reusable cmake helper scripts and using them in your projects via `file(DOWNLOAD) ` and then `include()`, or `FetchContent`.